# Header path inside of framework

Tags: ios, frameworks, header

I'm working with making framwork project in iOS.
I want to change whole project to framwork and use it in other application.
I make all header files to public, but header file include other header files like this

## include "subfolder/ClassName.h"

but if I use it in other application, can't find the "subfolder/ClassName.h"
maybe because of that files are in same "/Headers" folder..
How can I make it working ??

Comment: Have you added folders in your project as 'Create Folder References for added folders', this will allow you to access the data using ABCFolder/filename.h and also you need to create .a file of your project and then you should use it as a framework in other projects.

Comment: Here are the steps for doing it -  http://codefriend.blogspot.in/2011/09/creating-ios-framework-with-xcode4.html

Answer (score 1):

Inside your project's build settings, add the direct path for all header files under "Header Search Paths" and make it recursive in case there are any subfolders that also need inclusion.